# Odoo 8 - Custom theme : show menu created from administration interface

Tags: menu, odoo, odoo-8, qweb, odoo-website

I'm creating a custom theme for an Odoo online shop. I need to have a main menu, which would be the one that comes by default with the website module, and a secondary menu that I want to display on all pages, somewhere below the main menu.
I created the secondary menu in the backend, this what it looks like :

[image: Menu creation interface]

The "Top Menu" is the default menu, it shows properly in the top right of the website's pages. I just can't figure out how to show the "Navigation" menu in my templates.

Copying this piece of code from the website module anywhere in my templates shows the "Top Menu" :

```
<t t-foreach="website.menu_id.child_id" t-as="submenu">
    <t t-call="website.submenu"/>
</t>
```

So I guess this "Top Menu" is somehow associated to the website module right ? So do I need to "associate" the "Navigation" menu to my theme ? How would I do that ?
Or did I just do everything wrong ? I'm used to Wordpress' `wp_nav_menu` function with wich you can simply get a menu by its ID but maybe it's not the way to go with Odoo ? I'm having a hard time finding help on this matter in the doc or in forums.